# How to create a React Component that handles the Typescript type guard "is"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<User | undefined>(undefined);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Simulating fetched user data
    setTimeout(() => {
      setUser({ firstName: "John" }); // Set user data
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {user && (<div>Welcome {user.firstName}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is it possible to create a React component such that the typeguard "is" is handled so I can effectively remove the `{user && (` and do something like:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<User | undefined>(undefined);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Simulating fetched user data
    setTimeout(() => {
      setUser({ firstName: "John" }); // Set user data
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <RenderIfLoaded object={user}>
            <div>Welcome {user.firstName}</div>
        </RenderIfLoaded>
    </div>
  );
};
```

So basically inside the `RenderIfLoaded`, the user object is now guaranteed to be defined and TS would understand that

Comment: Your `RenderIfLoaded` component can just use the same logic that the first code snippet uses, wrapping the `children` of the component.  What did you try?

Comment: What's wrong with using the idiomatic `&&` pattern?

Comment: @David TS would still complain about `<div>Welcome {user.firstName}</div>` saying `user` can be undefined.

Comment: @Kousha: That would happen within `RenderIfLoaded` too, since its `object` prop would need to accept `undefined`.  Perhaps you're looking for [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for accessing properties on potentially `undefined` values?  It's a little unclear to me what the underlying problem is here.  TS is indicating that `user` might be `undefined` because it might be.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a component, similar to the one you have, that takes a prop representing the value that could be expected type `T` or `undefined` and `children` prop typed as a callback function that will render when the value is not `undefined`. You can add `null` as well or instead, whatever works for the use case.

So in typescript would look something like

```
import {ReactNode} from "react"

type Props<T> = {
    value:T|undefined
    children:(value:T)=>ReactNode
}

const Show = <T,>({value,children}:Props<T>)=>{
    if (value===undefined){
        return null
    }
    return children(value)
}
```

Then you use it like

```
const NameDisplay = (props: { name: string }) => props.name;

const Test = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  return <Show value={name}>{(name) => <NameDisplay name={name} />}</Show>;
};
```

Here `NameDisplay` only takes `string` for name props and will only be rendered if the value is not undefined.

This is similar to what solidjs does and works very well there and is quite nice to use, since solid uses signals rather than vdom, all reactive values are functions so you need these kind of control flow components to write render functions smoothly.

I'd say the important aspect here to consider is how the children prop is implemented as a callback so you can consider the non null or non undefined value and continue writing the render code without many complications.

You can check out the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAb0WJgDkIATJAGjgFcBnJAMowUMJHAC%20cbLgJF0MMuXIwAnmDEAFHGF4AeACoA%20OAF465OHABuKADbckALjj64AHx4A7dpmCekrBSWaAAWwLasRJ7OABQ29k4uAJSmxsjyLOwU4hTkaBCevPACIRAA7qZwBhyGMfTxDlyh4ZFInhLOWhA6BoYpJsa0FnDAmHBxdg6mJmbc3ki%20-qwpQ5aWRDDcUO2e3La2QRLDG1vtzRFREwlJ2bn5hfBMKCBIACLAvGC2KCqVMWDaXjOeieZ6JIpQPwAcwk-WMAO6vAAdKCXncCkUXEhMWYYnDzMEMfAANqozhwfjMMEAXUqfEEwlEugh0PcXh8fgCtTmHKWNyU6yQm22VRK5WskyQJloZPEhloMTJ%20N0Txe70%2031%20ZOlsrgAHpDOJdHqxWVDLdyEA) if it helps

If you're interested can look at more detail on how solid implements it https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/flow_show and https://github.com/solidjs/solid/blob/main/packages/solid/src/render/flow.ts#L86. It's not going to be the same in react but interesting to see.

Comment: I think using `type NonUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T;` would help here